# Create a dynamic table with adding column and row that depends on data in JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that I wish to make it more dynamic. 
How to change this code into dynamic table like for example.

**Example for Current Version and Revision Date column.**

If the *Current Version* and *Revision Date* th have a data it will create another column to make it 3 or 4 and so on *Current Version* and *Revision Date* column.

**Example for Remarks column.**

If the *Remarks* column have a data add another column inside *Remarks* column which is 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... and so on.

***Please see the sample output below.***

```
<table border="2" style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Document Name</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Document ID</th>
                    <th>Current Version</th>
                    <th>Current Version</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Remarks</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Signature</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <th>Revision Date</th>
                    <th>Revision Date</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">1st</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">2nd</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="resultAppend">

            </tbody>
        </table>





 <script>


var APIData = [{ Section_No: '4.1',
                           Document_Title: 'Sample Document Title',
                           Document_ID: 'QM-CI-001',
                           Revisions: [ { No: '01', 
                                          Approval_Date:'8/23/2017' },
                                        { No: '02', 
                                          Approval_Date: '3/12/2018' }, 
                                       ], 
                           remarks: [ 'OK', 'OK' ],
                           Signature: 'Signature' }];


        var trData = '';


        for (var i = 0; i < APIData.length; i++) {
            var obj = APIData[i];

            trData += '<tr >' +
                '<td rowspan="2">' + obj.Section_No + '</td>' +
                '<td rowspan="2">' + obj.Document_Title + '</td>' +
                '<td rowspan="2">' + obj.Document_ID + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + obj.Revision_No + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + obj.Revision_No + '</td>' +
                '<td rowspan="2">' + obj.remarks1 + '</td>' +
                '<td rowspan="2">' + obj.remarks2 + '</td>' +
                '<td rowspan="2">' + obj.Signature + '</td>' +
                '</tr><tr>' +
                '<td>' + obj.Approval_Date + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + obj.Approval_Date + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';

        }



        document.querySelector('#resultAppend').innerHTML = trData;
    </script>
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQDjX.png)

Comment: First of all, you should restructure your APIData. It is incorrect, as it is now, and as a result, your screen-shot has incorrect values. I would suggest something like:

`var APIData = [{
            Section_No: '4.1',
            Document_Title: 'Sample Document Title',
            Document_ID: 'QM-CI-001',
   Revisions: [
    { No: '01', Approval_Date: '8/23/2017' },
    { No: '02', Approval_Date: '3/12/2018' },
   ],
   remarks: [ 'OK', 'OK' ],
            Signature: 'Signature'
        }];
`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using the [JsViews](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsviews) package - it will fit to your task very well.

I have prepared an example using your sample data, extended for 2 rows: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/js5Lz4xv/)

Here is jsViews/jsRender template code:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Document Name</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Document ID</th>
            {{for ~makeArray(maxVersions)}}
            <th>Current Version</th>
            {{/for}}
            <th colspan="{{:maxRemarks}}">Remarks</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Signature</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {{for ~makeArray(maxVersions)}}
            <th>Revision Date</th>
            {{/for}}
            {{for ~makeArray(maxRemarks)}}
            <th rowspan="2">{{:~getNumberWithOrdinal(#index+1)}}</th>
            {{/for}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultAppend">
    {{for rows ~maxVersions = maxVersions ~maxRemarks = maxRemarks}}
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">{{:Section_No}}</td>
            <td rowspan="2">{{:Document_Title}}</td>
            <td rowspan="2">{{:Document_ID}}</td>
            {{for Revisions}}
            <td>{{:#data.No}}</td>
            {{/for}}
            {{for ~makeArray(~maxVersions - Revisions.length)}}
            <td></td>
            {{/for}}
            {{for remarks}}
            <td rowspan="2">{{:#data}}</td>
            {{/for}}
            {{for ~makeArray(~maxRemarks - remarks.length)}}
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            {{/for}}
            <td rowspan="2">{{:Signature}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {{for Revisions}}
            <td>{{:#data.Approval_Date}}</td>
            {{/for}}
            {{for ~makeArray(~maxVersions - Revisions.length)}}
            <td></td>
            {{/for}}
        </tr>
    {{/for}}    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And JS:

```
var APIData = [
  { 
    Section_No: '4.1',
    Document_Title: 'Sample Document Title',
    Document_ID: 'QM-CI-001',
    Revisions: [ 
      { No: '01', Approval_Date:'8/23/2017' },
      { No: '02', Approval_Date: '3/12/2018' }, 
    ], 
    remarks: [ 'OK', 'OK' ],
    Signature: 'Signature' 
  },
  { 
    Section_No: '4.2',
    Document_Title: 'Sample Document Title 2',
    Document_ID: 'QM-CI-002',
    Revisions: [ 
      { No: '01', Approval_Date: '3/12/2018' }, 
    ], 
    remarks: [ 'OK', 'OK', 'OK' ],
    Signature: 'Signature2' 
  },
];

$.views.helpers({
  getNumberWithOrdinal: function(n) {
    var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
    v=n%100;
    return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]); },
  makeArray: function(count) {
    var array = [];
    if(count) { array[count-1] = {}; }
    return array;
  }
});

var template = $.templates("#theTmpl");

var data = {
  maxVersions: 1,
  maxRemarks: 1,
  rows: APIData
};

APIData.forEach(function(row){
  var versions = row.Revisions.length;
  if( versions > data.maxVersions) { data.maxVersions = versions; }
  var remarks = row.remarks.length;
  if( remarks > data.maxRemarks) { data.maxRemarks = remarks; }
});

template.link("#result", data);
```

Comment: Can you show me what version of JSRender you are using I have an error on helpers. Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined. Reference https://jsfiddle.net/rxdqvcka/

Comment: When you open [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/js5Lz4xv/) from me, click to the Resources line. Here you could see, that I used the jquery.min.js and jsviews.min.js. Clicking on their names, will open them in the browser and there you could see the CDN URLs:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/1.0.2/jsviews.min.js

Comment: In fact, `template.link("#result", data);` is jsViews command, so you will need to use jsViews instead of jsRender. Otherwise both products have the similar design and the same template language - I will correct my answer